# How to debug error 403 on Rest API with valid token with Python Requests package

Tags: python, python-requests, adobe

I'm new to using APIs and I'm trying to access an Adobe Rest API using the Requests package.
I have managed to get a token but I get a 403 error (logged out) with any request I attempt.

I have performed the OAuth Authentication successfully and, Using a Legacy Application Flow (required by Adobe), I've fetched a token that grants me read and write access. I've tried a few get requests get the 403, session expired error. 
I've looked up online and tried to clear my cookies before generating a new token, with the same results. However the token generated works fine with Postman and I can do get requests from there, so it doesn't seem to have anything to do with authentification/credentials/session.
Adobe helpdesk have no clue as to why this is happening either!

---

Here is the token I get back after identification:

```
{'access_token': 'some-encoded-string',
 'expires_at': 1552652569.358807,
 'expires_in': 3599,
 'refresh_token': 'some-encoded-string',
 'scope': ['read', 'write'],
 'token_type': 'bearer'}
```

---

---

Here is the request and error:
    r = requests.get('https://url-endpoint')

```
r : <Response [403]>

r.json()
{'code': 'ACCESS_DENIED',
 'message': 'Your session has expired. Please proceed to the login page'}
```

---

I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working or even where to start!

Comment: Could you please share some code on how you are using the token to call the endpoint

Comment: I see that your token `1552652569.358807` indeed expired more than a week ago: 03/15/2019 @ 12:22pm (UTC)

Comment: Yes that's because the example is old, but I didn't work then.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I don't actually pass the token anywhere, which might be where I go wrong...how would you do this? At the moment I just fetch it like so before inputting the get request shown in my original post ---- 
   token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url='https://api.xxx.com/oauth/token',
        username=username, password=password, client_id=client_id,
        client_secret=client_secret) ----

Comment: I think you can try custom headers (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) in order to pass your authorization token

Comment: Have you tried `requests.Session`?

Answer (score 0):

@Devesh Kumar Singh yes that's the right idea, I forgot one step - in the end I used
 client = OAuth2Session(client_id, token=token)
and from there
r = client.get('https://url-endpoint', params=params) works perfectly.